# Nunjucks Template Refresh

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, nunjucks

I have been using PHP to do server-side includes but many pages on my site could be static and benefit from a build workflow to automate static generation.

Nunjucks and Gulp was my choice and everything is working fine with extending layouts, includes, passing data from variables etc.

When I update a page, Browser-sync enables me to auto-update connected browsers for all resources (I've stripped out unnecessary tasks) all except changes to my nunjucks files. Refreshing the browser does not help.

Making changes on the page that uses the changed templates is one solution for that single page.
Restarting the server is another solution to update all pages with the template changes.

I've added a watch to try and fix the issue. It does not produce an error nor does it give the desired result.

I can live with this but it would be nice to see those template updates if anyone can help.

```js
/* Gulpfile.js */
const gulp                      = require('gulp'),
      del                       = require('del'),
      plumber                   = require('gulp-plumber'),
      browserSync               = require('browser-sync').create(),
      nunjucksRender            = require('gulp-nunjucks-render'),

      src_folder                = './src/',
      dest_folder               = './dest/';

gulp.task('clear', () => del([ dest_folder ]));

gulp.task('html', () => {
  return gulp.src([ src_folder + 'html/**/*.html' ], {
    since: gulp.lastRun('html')
  })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_folder))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('nunjucks', () => {
  return gulp.src([ src_folder + 'html/**/*.html'], {
    //base: src_folder + 'views',
    since: gulp.lastRun('nunjucks')
  })
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['src/views']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest_folder))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('build', gulp.series('clear', 'html', 'nunjucks'));

gulp.task('dev', gulp.series('html', 'nunjucks'));

gulp.task('serve', () => {
  return browserSync.init({
    server: { baseDir: [ 'dest' ] },
    port: 3000,
    open: false
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', () => {

  const watch = [
    src_folder + 'html/**/*.html',
    src_folder + 'views/**/*.njk'
  ];

  gulp.watch(watch, gulp.series('dev')).on('change', browserSync.reload);

  /* My failed attempt to see template updates */
  gulp.watch(src_folder + 'views/**/*.njk').on('change', gulp.series('nunjucks', 'html', function (done) {
     console.log('Has my process completed?');
      done();
  }));

});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build', gulp.parallel('serve', 'watch')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, that took me a while to track this problem down. It was just a case of removing one snippet of code from this:

```
  return gulp.src([ 'glob'], {
    since: gulp.lastRun('taskName')
  })
```

to this:

```
  return gulp.src('glob')
```

I was watching my HTML and the templates. Changes to the HTML files was reloading in the browser fine ... but any changes to the templates were not being updated.

It was down to that `lastRun()` method.
I added it for a performance boost.
When updating a template and then calling the nunjucks task, lastRun was ignoring the HTML pages because they had not changed.

*Is it possible to get the performance boost without breaking the template updates?*

I don't know, except by creating two different tasks with corresponding watchers, one for HTML pages, using  `lastRun()` and the other for their templates without it.